# Git Bash performance issue, very slow push process even with small changes for an already existed project inside repository

Tags: git-bash

This issue just recently occurs when I tried to commit some small changes for an already existing 900KB project inside the repository using these commands with Git Bash:

```
git add .
git add -u
git commit -m "changes"
git pull --rebase
git push -u origin main
```

Before, these commands can push the project changes with reasonable time usage until today that it decide to stuck at the "writing object" process for a very long time and still not finished (25 minutes+):

```
Enumerating objects: 28, done.
Counting objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects:  94% (16/17), 31.66 MiB | 15.00 KiB/s
```

What is the cause of this issue and how can I solve it?

I use both

> git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400

and

> git gc

but none of these commands help solve this issue.

**UPDATE**
: The process just finished, it took almost 1 hour with such a small modification push! This situation is not normal at all and should be resolved.

Comment: Do you know if a big file was added? Do you know about network speed? 15KB/s sounds like a low throughput.

Comment: where is your git server hosted? Locally? github? another provider? Maybe you got rate limited by provider

Comment: My git server is located at GitHub. And no big file was added at all, only small code changes. The biggest file in this project is the source code itself which is only 850KB.